# Why does PHP-generated content jitter when loaded trough jQuery, and how do I fix it?

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

When I generate PHP within a file that is asynchronously loaded by jQuery, the text seems to jitter or flicker a little while the animation runs. This does not happen to the regular HTML in the requested file, only the content generated with PHP.

Just want some hints as to what can end the jitter.

Here is the jQuery in the `main.php`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var demo = $('#demo');
    demo.hide();
    $("button").click(function(){
        demo.load('demo.php', function() {
        demo.show('medium');
        });
    });
});
```

Here is the HTML and PHP in `demo.php`:

```
<p><?php echo "Hello World with PHP trough AJAX"; ?></p>
```

I’m really unsure where to begin. Should I just avoid using PHP in `demo.php` alltogether? Even so I'd really like to have to possibility to use PHP in scripts called trough AJAX.

As per request, here is the whole darn thing:

`main.php`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Testing Ajax</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css" />
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var demo = $('#demo');
            demo.hide();
            $("button").click(function(){
                demo.load('demo.php', function() {
                    demo.show('medium');
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        #demo {background-color: MidnightBlue;color: white;padding: 0.1em 1em 1.5em 1.5em;}
        #demo h1 {color: white;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <section>
        <article>
            <h1>Ajax</h1>
            <hr />
            <button>Load External Content</button>
            <div id="demo"></div>
        </article>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

(I like MidnightBlue better than CornflowerBlue...)

`demo.php`:

```
<h1>Ajax criex Hello World!</h1>
<p><?php echo "PHP also cries Hello World trough Ajax!"; ?></p>
```

Comment: *Asnwer to deleted Q*: Yes, but the PHP is only generated when the script is loaded by jQuery. It's like the server suddenly remembered that "Oh sh**, I also need to add the PHP-generated content. Aaah, just made it!" There is really nothing more to show. Just add some static test HTML next to the PHP, and you'll see it renders just fine when called.

Comment: You're also not even using AJAX in the code you have supplied.

Comment: @Killrawr - `jQuery.load` is an alias API for an AJAX request

Comment: Could be a number for things from how initally make the object hidden to the animation starting before the element is in the dom... but we need to see your html.. both the snippet coming beck from php and the relevant portion of the page making the ajax call.

Comment: @Chris oh I didn't know that, I thought the main way was `$.ajax({})`.

Comment: @Killrawr N/p, check out the manual for more :D http://api.jquery.com/load/

Kebman - define "jitter", and let's see the basic HTML you're modifying with the callback HTML.

Comment: @Kebman It might be a problem with your HTML (Document Object Model). Things you can do to possibly fix the `jitter` would be to check if your code validates server-side on [W3C HTML validator](http://validator.w3.org/) (Browsers don't compile HTML, they just render it).

Comment: In addition to Chris comment, Kebman you could also supply us with a jsfiddle that is doing an ajax request to the URL (visual definition of `jitter`).

Comment: Jitter: As long as the animation runs, the sentence from PHP jumps a round a little at startup, like it's being assembled and put in place. Only the PHP-generated stuff reacts like that, not the static HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically speaking, there is absolutely no difference between text generated with PHP versus text generated in ASP.net versus text contained in a .txt file versus text caused by typing on your keyboard -- it is all letters and numbers. Indeed, I would go as far to say that, examining text absent other clues, it is completely and 100% impossible to tell how it was created. No, you should not avoid PHP with AJAX.

Any "jittering" that you see is a product of some other issue, most likely related to browser performance - processor availability, free memory, current process memory consumption, extension activity/interference with page content, etc.

Comment: Then why does only the PHP-generated content in demo.php jitter, and not other content in the same file?

Comment: Again, there is some other technical reason. Without other details, it is hard to say. Is the server localhost? What you mean by "jitter"?

Thing is... AJAX is used by thousands of major sites around the internet, including major players like Google and Apple. It is a well-established technique and most certainly does not cause visual display issues within your browser, generally speaking.

Comment: Yes, it's localhost on my Core2 Duo MacBook with a MySQL/Apache installation. It is least apparent on FireFox, but shows really well in Chrome and Safari.

Comment: I would suspect processor availability and/or memory use, then. What happens is that the request fires and starts consuming resources as your local server responds. The resource demand will be heavier with a PHP file than with an HTML file. The response is sent by the server and the resources allocated to the server start to free up, but the browser is already chewing up some now to rebuild DOM and perform the animation. Check your server configuration to optimize memory consumption, and test it on a web-based host (check out http://www.000webhost.com/, free).

Comment: Especially if xDebug is on, or if you've got your memory limit cranked up... there are a ton of PHP, Apache, and MySQL settings that can affect performance. I am completely confident that the issue is caused by resource availability -- the symptoms you describe are simply the browser doing a bad job of drawing javascript-based animations... this is not a surprise. There isn't a better option, but that means we're stuck with the limitations, including poor smoothness when low resources are available. Options include buying memory, animating less, or using Flash! Yuck. :D

Comment: Lol, this is not exactly some kind of processor heavy 3D game... No don't have any of those settings on. But OK, I'll put it on an external site, and test it on another computer. :)

Comment: You're right that, normally speaking, the XAMP-like setup isn't overtly processor intensive, but it can be with just a few wayward settings. Plus, you're running a text editor, plus a browser, plus possibly Photoshop, plus possibly Spotify, plus... plus... plus... you get the idea :) It **is** just a little laptop, after all.

Comment: It's kind of a no-answer answer, but I'll accept it as I haven't seen anything better. Cherone's answer might also be right, however I've seen this problem other places too, so I'm not sure it's due to the infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will help you. Probably not if the code shown above is `really` all your code.

But: Some time back I also had a jittering problem in animations when I loaded content via Ajax. The reason was: The loaded content contained Javascript code with other animation commands and then both animations interfered. Maybe this is also the case here.

Answer (score 1):

In my test whilst trying to reproduce the "jitter" your code is producing an **infinite ajax loop** (View it in Web Console, your see) thats most likely your jitter effect:

Heres a basic PHP and AJAX example:

```
<?php 
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) === 'xmlhttprequest' && $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && isset($_POST['action'])){
    $action = $_POST['action'];
    switch($action){
        case "hello":
            echo "Hello World with PHP through AJAX";
            break;
        case "foobar":
            echo "Hello Foobar";
            break;
    }
    die;
}
?>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
           var action = this.value;
           ajaxload('demo',action);
    });
});
function ajaxload(placement,action){
    $.post("./demo.php", { 'action': action },
    function(data) {
        $("#"+placement).hide().html(data).fadeIn('slow');
    });
}
</script>


<button type="button" value="hello">Hello World</button>
<button type="button" value="foobar">Foobar</button>


<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: Lol, question is... How do you *end* the jittering?